# How to set background color to transparent status bar

Tags: android-layout, colors, window, styles, statusbar

Is it possible to change the background color of a transparent status bar programmatically?

I have set my status bar to be transparent using the following code so I can also have my navigation drawer in the status bar without the status bar overlapping the navigation drawer.

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

The status bar takes the background color from

`<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>`

Is it possible to change this color programmatically and have the status bar still be transparent?

I tried using

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(statusBarColor);
```

but the status bar has a ugly dark scrim over it, which I do not want.

Is there any other way to archieve this programmatically? I need to be able to change the color at runtime. Also having different styles for each color is not an option because the user should be able to select the color.

EDIT: This is what I mean by the status bar overlapping the navigation drawer when changing its color by using `setStatusBarColor(int);`. I still want the navigation drawer to overlap the status bar.

[image]

Comment: You are already setting color as transparent, so you can't set another color on transparent bar.

Comment: @OnkarNene but isn't there a way to change the color below the transparency? setting primaryDark also changes it, so there has to be a way to change it even if it is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way.

```
// Check if the version of Android is Lollipop or higher
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

    // Set the status bar to dark-semi-transparentish
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);


}
```

**UpDate :**

Instead of

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Use the following:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

**UpDate2 :**

**styles.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>
```

**colors.xml**

```
 <color name="colorPrimary">#0072BA</color>
 <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#004F80</color>
 <color name="colorAccent">#005D96</color>
```

**Output :**

without drawer

[image]

with drawer

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does leave a dark scrim on top of the status bar, which is not what I want.

Comment: the color appears way darker than it should be because android applies a dark tint on top of it when using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS`. Also I literally just wrote in the question that I tried this already and it didn't work.

Comment: again, this does leave a dark scrim on the status bar, making my color appear way darker than it should

Comment: and how to change the status bar color now without modifying the xml?

Comment: I want to set the background color of the status bar programmatically, and it should appear like on the picture, without any dark scrim on it and without it overlapping the navigation drawer.